# How to use pointers in LeetCode Two Sum problem in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, nested-loops

I am new to LeetCode and my only background in C is a single class of its basics. I wish to improve and learn more. I think my problem here is with the pointers or malloc. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int *ans;
    ans = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 2;

    for(int i=0; i<numsSize; i++){
        for(int j=i++ ; j<numsSize; j++){
            if( nums[i] + nums[j] == target ){
                ans[0] = i;
                ans[1] = j;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    return *ans;
}
```

This is the error:

> Line 207: Char 3: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x000000000001 for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment [**Serializer**.c]
> 0x000000000001: note: pointer points here

From what I understand with pointers:

- `*ans[0] = i` should have assigned the value of i, which is an integer, to the value that the pointer ans[0] points to. However, this gives an error "error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)". So, I instead tried the code above.
- 'return *ans' should have returned the array [i,j]?

Comment: The function has type `int*` and `ans` is the same type so you should `return ans;`.

Comment: The loop `for(int j=i++ ; j<numsSize; j++)` looks suspicious. The outer loop's `i` has two incrementers. Did you mean `for(int j=i+1 ; j<numsSize; j++)`?

Comment: The first thing to do is fix your warnings.  Those are bugs.  Your function is declared to return an `int *`, but you're trying to return an `int`.  Change `return *ans;` to `return ans;`  Remember, `*ans` has type `int`, and `ans` has type `int *`.

Comment: Note that `break` only breaks the inner loop. Depending on the problem requirements you might want to `return arr;` just there, and `return NULL;` at the end of the function to indicate to the caller that the `target` was not matched.

Comment: You *could* change that `break;` to `return ans;` since the answer has been found. I don't know what the function is supposed to do if no answer has been found when the outer loop terminates, possibly `free(ans);` `return NULL;`?

Comment: The question would be improved by addition of a specification of what the function is supposed to do.  LeetCode problem names are not particularly meaningful outside LeetCode.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pointer `int* ptr` in C, you can dereference it (get to the object it is pointing to) with the operator `*` like `*ptr`. Or, if there is memory allocated (e.g. via `malloc()`) for multiple objects, you can get to each of them with `*(ptr + i)` where `i` stands for the offset to the object you want to retrieve. However if `i` is negative or bigger/equal to the amount of objects you allocated memory for, you access memory out of boundaries which is undefined behavior and can result in a segmentation fault.

Since writing `*(ptr + i)` is a bit ugly and harder to read, you can use `ptr[i]` instead, which does the same thing.

---

> `*ans[0] = i` should have assigned the value of i

You can eiter use `*ans = i` or `*(ans + 0) = i` or `ans[0] = i` to get a working result. All three of these options do the same, but I would favor the last, since you have an array and not just a single element which your pointer is pointing to. (If its only a single one, you should use `*ans` to make it easier to read and understand that it is not an array.)

> `return *ans` should have returned the array [i,j]

Same problem again. When you dereference it like `*ans`, you don't return the whole array, but only the first thing it is pointing to, which is the integer `i`. Instead you should `return ans;`.

In your inner `for` loop you use `int j=i++`, which does set `j` to be `i` and then increments `i` by one. That is not the behavior you want, since it makes `i` jump over one whole iteration which could lead to you skipping the values you are looking for. And `i` and `j` are the same, for the first iteration, but the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/) states that this should not be the case. So you could just use `int j = i + 1` in your inner `for` loop.

---

The rest of your code should work, but it could be improved a bit. I suppose that you want to exit out of both of your `for` loops at the `break` statement in your `if`? `break` only exists the inner loop, which is not getting you wrong results since the problems description states "Only one valid answer exists", but you could just `return ans;` to exit immediately. Otherwise you could use some additional variable or `goto` to jump to the end of your function.

And you don't check what `malloc()` returns you. If it returns `NULL` (although that probably won't happen), then your program will crash when you try to dereference `ans`.

---

The problem does not say what should happen, if you don't find a valid pair, but I think "Only one valid answer exists" means that there is always one valid answer, not more and not less. I assumed for my solution that I might not find a pair, and only allocated `ans` and set `*returnSize` to `2` if I actually found one.

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    *returnSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                int* ans = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
                if (ans != NULL) {
                    *returnSize = 2;
                    ans[0] = i;
                    ans[1] = j;
                }
                return ans;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

---

> I am new to LeetCode and my only background in C is a single class of its basics.

I think I should add to this answer that LeetCode might be fun or you think it helps you to learn a language or help you get hired somewhere, but is not the right place to start with a new language and does not teach you best practice.

In my opinion the goal of LeetCode is to get a deeper understanding of algorithms and data structures, but you need to know the language you are using beforehand. If you only know some basics and struggle with the first easy problem I would suggest that you first learn a bit more about the language before trying to solve some LeetCode problems.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with the function.

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int *ans;
    ans = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 2;

    for(int i=0; i<numsSize; i++){
        for(int j=i++ ; j<numsSize; j++){
            if( nums[i] + nums[j] == target ){
                ans[0] = i;
                ans[1] = j;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    return *ans;
}
```

The first one is that the expression `*ans` has type `int` but the return type is `int *`. You need to return a pointer instead of an object of the type `int`.

```
return ans;
```

Pay attention to that the expression `*ans` is equivalent to the expression `ans[0]`.

The second problem is using the postfix increment operator `i++` in the inner for loop. Due to this increment some elements of the array pointed to by the pointer `nums` wll be skipped because the variable `i` is incremented a second time in the outer for loop.

The `break` statement used in the inner for loop breaks only the inner for loop.

The function returns a pointer to an allocated dynamically array

```
ans = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
*returnSize = 2;
```

but if neither elements in the array that are equal to `target` were found the caller of the function will be unable to determine that.

Also pay attention to that `LeetCode` teaches to bad style of programming. At least the function should be declared like

```
size_t * twoSum( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, int target );
```

The fourth parameter is redundant. If there is no two elements in the array that are equal to target the function can just return a null pointer. It is clear without the parameter `returnSize` that returned pointer can point to an array of two elements due to the task of the function.

The functon can be defined the following way

```
size_t * twoSum( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, int target )
{
    size_t *ans = NULL;

    if ( !( numsSize < 2 ) )
    {
        int found = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 0; !found && i < numsSize; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = i + 1;
            while ( j < numsSize && nums[i] + nums[j] != target ) ++j;

            if ( j != numsSize )
            {
                found = 1;
                ans = malloc( 2 * sizeof( *ans ) );
                if ( ans != NULL )
                {
                    nums[0] = i;
                    nums[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

and in the caller you could check whether the returned pointer is not equal to NULL the following way

```
size_t *ans = twoSum( nums, numsSize, target );

if ( ans != NULL )
{
    // do something with the returned indices in the dynamically allocated array
}
```

Though it would be even better to return a structure of two members instead of the dynamically allocated array. Something like

```
struct Pair 
{ 
    size_t first; 
    size_t second; 
};
```

In this case the function can look the following way

```
struct Pair twoSum( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, int target )
{
    struct Pair ans = { .first = 0, .second = 0 };

    if ( !( numsSize < 2 ) )
    {
        int found = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 0; !found && i < numsSize; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = i + 1;
            while ( j < numsSize && nums[i] + nums[j] != target ) ++j;

            if ( j != numsSize )
            {
                found = 1;
                ans.first  = i;
                ans.second = j;
            }
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

And in the caller you could write

```
struct Pair ans = twoSum( nums, numsSize, target );

if ( ans.first != ans.second )
{
    // do something with the returned indices
}
```